# JMeter - How to extract Properties data from the Sample Result tab

Tags: jmeter

After using JMS Subscriber, is it possible to extract the Properties data from the Sample Result tab.

```
Response headers:
JMSCorrelationId null
JMSMessageId     ID:yyy-me-me-7:1:1:1:1725
JMSTimestamp     1400089667055
JMSType          null
JMSExpiration    0
JMSPriority      4
JMSDestination   topic://xyz
Properties:
NAME    3bdfe64dd452.xxx
PATH    
TYPE    XXX
OP      CREATE
REL 


SampleResult fields:
ContentType: 
DataEncoding: null
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract JMS headers normally using [Regular Expression Extractor](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter) Post-Processor. For instance, if you want to get `JMSMessageId`

1. Add Regular Expression Extractor as a child of the request which returns above headers
2. Configure it as follows:

   - Field to check: `Response headers`
   - Name of created variable: anything meaningful, i.e. `JMSMessageId`
   - Regular Expression: `JMSMessageId (.*)`
   - Template: `$1$`

     [image: JMeter JMS Header Extraction]
3. That's it, now you should have the value stored in `JMSMessageId` [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) and will be able to refer it as `${JMSMessageId}` where required. The value can be validated using [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler)

   [image: JMeter Variable Value Check via Debug Sampler]

---

If you want to store **all headers** change your Regular Expression to be `(?s)(^.*)`.